# Overload on ostream in a variadic template function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, overload-resolution

I have a variadic function that I want to overload on the first parameter type.

```
void write( void ) { }

void write( std::ostream& ) { }

template< typename Head, typename... Rest >
void write( std::ostream& out, Head&& head, Rest&&... rest )
{
   out << head;
   write( out, std::forward<Rest>(rest)... );
}

template< typename... Args >
void write( Args&&... args )
{
   write( std::cout, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}
```

But these functions don't behave as expected.

```
write( "## to cout ##" ); // printed to stdout as expected
write( std::cerr, "## to cerr ##" ); // printed to stderr as expected
std::ostringstream oss;
write( oss, "## to string ##" );  // error here
// '0x7fff9db8## to string ##' is printed to stdout!
```

What's going on here?
Why isn't overload resolution picking the function I want?
Is there a way to do this without lots of metaprogramming? (I was able to work around it with `std::is_convertible` but the solution was much larger than the simple code I've shown above).

Comment: Why do you need the last template specialization? The problem would go away without that one.

Comment: @Diego, The last specialization (`write(args)`) puts `std::cout` as the first argument if an ostream object wasn't supplied by the caller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `ostringstream` needs a base conversion to `ostream` when you pass it to the other template, while it doesn't need any conversion when you pass it to the template that forwards to `write(std::cout, ...)`. So if you pass `ostringstream`, it selects the more generic template which forwards the ostringstream as an argument to output to the more specific template. Outputting the `ostringstream` converts it to a `void*`, which is then printed.

You can solve this with `is_base_of` (just feels better to me than using `is_convertible`).

```
template<typename Arg, typename... Args, typename =
  typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_base_of<
      std::ostream,
      typename std::remove_reference<Arg>::type, 
      >::value>::type
>
void write(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args )
{
   write( std::cout, std::forward<Arg>(arg), std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}
```

I personally dislike using too much SFINAE in my code, because I can't cope with a certain level of angle brackets. So I like to use overloading

```
template< typename Arg, typename... Args >
void write_dispatch( std::true_type, Arg&& arg, Args&&... args )
{
   std::ostream& os = arg;
   write( os, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}

template< typename Arg, typename... Args >
void write_dispatch( std::false_type, Arg&& arg, Args&&... args )
{
   write( std::cout, std::forward<Arg>(arg), std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}

template< typename Arg, typename... Args >
void write( Arg&& arg, Args&&... args )
{
   typedef typename std::remove_reference<Arg>::type nonref_type;
   write_dispatch( std::is_base_of<std::ostream, nonref_type>(), 
          std::forward<Arg>(arg), std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}
```

This way, if you call it with something other than lvalue of `ostream` as first argument, it will call `write_dispatch`, which will transform the call into such an lvalue of `ostream`, so that your other `write` template can continue.

On a final note, you should say `out << std::forward<Head>(head)`, otherwise all your work to use `std::forward` in previous recursion steps would be for naught, because in the end you would output everything as lvalues anyway.

Comment: So you're saying overload resolution prefers T&& over a base class conversion?  Is there a way I can tweak the signature to avoid this?

Comment: @deft_code, as I assume you found out, you can do this with `is_convertible<T, std::ostream&>` or `is_base_of<std::ostream, T>`.

Comment: @litb, won't `is_base_of` also be true when the T privately inherits from `std::ostream`?  I don't know why anyone would do that but it would cause the `static_cast` in the example to not compile.

Comment: @deft correct. I suppose it's a question of semantics. I wouldn't mind if a class that privately derives from `ostream` fails to compile when used with `write`. The `write_dispatch` will fail if a `const` stream was passed. Would I have used a c-style cast there, it would cast away the const and it would silently forward it as a non-const stream. I think `std::is_convertible<Arg, std::ostream&>` will work too, also for stuff like `struct A { operator std::ostream&(); };`. I think it's a matter of taste whether or not to treat `A` as a stream. I wouldn't.

Comment: @litb, I'm imagining the pathological case where a custom class privately derives from `ostream` but also supplies the stream insertion operator.  I'd imagine the user would want the class to stream out like it does with `std::cout`.

Comment: @deft_code such a class would be almost useless because almost every library defines its `operator<<` as `(ostream& os, ...)` or `(basic_ostream<T, U> &os, ...)`. In fact, your original code, if it worked, wouldn't expect such a class to be used with it either.